# disable user interaction if they are the last ones on a $x value

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

So i've banging my head to the wall for the last 2 days
So my issue is with this line

elseif ($current_user->ID == $bhistory['userid'])

i want the users to get error, if they are the last ones of $bhistory

my issue is that its not working, users are the last ones of $bhistory and they still able to click and  be the last ones again and again and again of $bhistory again.

also please can someone explain this line of code in english

foreach($bidding_history as $kk => $bhistory){

```
<?php
global $current_user;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
// MAKE BID OPTIONS
if($auction_type != 2){

    // BIDDING DATA
    $BIDDINGSTRING = "";

    // CHECK IF THIS IS AN AFFILIATE PRODUCT OR NOT
    $aff_p = get_post_meta($post->ID,'buy_link',true);
    if(strlen($aff_p) > 1){
    $link_l = get_home_url()."/out/".$post->ID."/buy_link/";
    $btn_l = "<a href='".$link_l."' class='btn btn-primary right'>".$CORE->_e(array('auction','53'))."</a>";

    // STOP BIDDING ON OWN ITEMS & IF LAST BIDDER
    }elseif ($current_user->ID == $bhistory['userid']){
    $btn_l = "<button class='btn' href='javascript:void(0);' onclick=\"alert('".$CORE->_e(array('auction','54'))."');\" id='bid_button'>".$CORE->_e(array('auction','70'))."</button>";
    }else{ if($userdata->ID == $post->post_author) {
    $btn_l = "<button class='btn' href='javascript:void(0);' onclick=\"alert('".$CORE->_e(array('auction','54','flag_noedit'))."');\" id='bid_button'>".$CORE->_e(array('auction','70'))."</button>";
    }else{
    $btn_l = "<button class='btn' href='javascript:void(0);' onclick=\"UpdateBidding();\" id='bid_button'>".$CORE->_e(array('auction','70'))."</button>";
    }
    }
```

S

Comment: http://php.net/foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to explain the line you requested with an example:

```
/*
 * Example: $bidding_history = array(
 *                                  'a'=>array('1','2'),
 *                                  'b'=>array('3','4')
 *                              )
 */
foreach($bidding_history as $kk => $bhistory){

}
```

For each element in $bidding_history as identified by the key $kk ('a','b') select the value of $bidding_history[$kk].

This would output something like that:
1st loop: $kk = 'a' and $bhistory = array('1','2')
2nd loop: $kk = 'b' and $bhistory = array('3','4')

I'm not fluent in english but I hope i made it clear.

Comment: thanks a lot, you helped me understand the foreach function which led to fixing the issue. Thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

at first you should control it for empty or not.

```
if (!empty($current_user) && $current_user->ID == $bhistory['userid'])
```

foreach;

```
foreach($bidding_history as $kk => $bhistory)
echo $bhistory['username'];
```

=

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($bidding_history); $i++)
echo $bidding_history[$i]['username'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this to check if the current user is the same as the last in the array

```
$last_user = end($bidding_history)
elseif ($current_user->ID == $last_user['userid']);
```